# Iron Web Scraper - Login

Tags: authentication, screen-scraping

I've read the tutorials to log into a website prior to scraping it, but it just ain't workin'. I constructed a HttpIdentity object, added it to the Identities collection, and processed the request, but the page returned to scrape was still the login page. There isn't a lot about this on their website and documentation. Here's my code for that:

```
var identity = new HttpIdentity
        {
            UseCookies = true,
            NetworkUsername = _username,
            NetworkPassword = _password
        };

        Identities.Add(identity);

        Request(_uri, Parse, identity);
```

In the Parse method I get a Response object returned with a Status Code of 200, and the "WasSuccessful" property of Response is "true". It seems that I should be redirected to the page I was trying to access, but I'm just getting the login html.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution using the Iron Web Scraper, but I was able to do it with ScrapySharp, which is a free utility, so it worked out. ScrapySharp is able to mimic a browser to a degree, so navigation and submitting forms is pretty easy.

```
var browser = new ScrapingBrowser();

var homepage = browser.NavigateToPage(_Uri); // login Uri

var form = homepage.FindForm("login"); // get form by name

form.Method = HttpVerb.Post;

form["username"] = "my_username"; // get form fields by id
form["password"] = "my_password";

var resultPage = form.Submit(); // login

var loggedInPage = browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("https://path.to.target.page"));
```

And that's it. I'm not sure what the problem was with Iron Web Scraper. Maybe some ajax on the login page. In any case, this code is working for me now.